# Make a dictionary in Python from input values

Tags: python, dictionary

Seems simple, yet elusive, want to build a dict from input of [key,value] pairs separated by a space using just one Python statement.  This is what I have so far:

```
d={}
n = 3
d = [ map(str,raw_input().split()) for x in range(n)]
print d
```

Input:

```
A1023 CRT
A1029 Regulator
A1030 Therm
```

Desired Output:

```
{'A1023': 'CRT', 'A1029': 'Regulator', 'A1030': 'Therm'}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `str.splitlines()` and `str.split()`:

```
strs="""A1023 CRT
        A1029 Regulator
        A1030 Therm"""
    
dict(x.split() for x in strs.splitlines())
```

result:

```
{'A1023': 'CRT', 'A1029': 'Regulator', 'A1030': 'Therm'}
```

more info:

> str.splitlines([keepends]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the lines in S, breaking at line boundaries. Line
> breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is given
> and true.

> str.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the delimiter
> string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit splits are done. If
> sep is not specified or is None, any whitespace string is a separator
> and empty strings are removed from the result.

Comment: Argv! You beat me to it by exactly one second. Deleting mine

Answer (score 19):

This is what we ended up using:

```
n = 3
d = dict(raw_input().split() for _ in range(n))
print d
```

Input:

```
A1023 CRT
A1029 Regulator
A1030 Therm
```

Output:

```
{'A1023': 'CRT', 'A1029': 'Regulator', 'A1030': 'Therm'}
```

Comment: The variable name _ is a traditional idiom for "Don't care."   As such, any variable name would suffice even though its value is never used.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = int(input("enter a n value:"))
d = {}

for i in range(n):
    keys = input() # here i have taken keys as strings
    values = int(input()) # here i have taken values as integers
    d[keys] = values
print(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(n):
    data = input().split(' ')
    d[data[0]] = data[1]
for keys,values in d.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
n = int(input())          #n is the number of items you want to enter
d ={}                     
for i in range(n):        
    text = input().split()     #split the input text based on space & store in the list 'text'
    d[text[0]] = text[1]       #assign the 1st item to key and 2nd item to value of the dictionary
print(d)
```

INPUT:

```
3

A1023 CRT

A1029 Regulator

A1030 Therm
```

NOTE: I have added an extra line for each input for getting each input on individual lines on this site. As placing without an extra line creates a single line.

OUTPUT:

```
{'A1023': 'CRT', 'A1029': 'Regulator', 'A1030': 'Therm'}
```

Comment: This returns error: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
when I entered A1023 CRT.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the text in variable `s`:

```
dict(map(lambda l: l.split(), s.splitlines()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input())
pair = dict()

for i in range(0,n):
        word = input().split()
        key = word[0]
        value = word[1]
        pair[key]=value

print(pair)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
record = int(input("Enter the student record need to add :"))

stud_data={}

for i in range(0,record):
    Name = input("Enter the student name :").split()
    Age = input("Enter the {} age :".format(Name))
    Grade = input("Enter the {} grade :".format(Name)).split()
    Nam_key =  Name[0]
    Age_value = Age[0]
    Grade_value = Grade[0]
    stud_data[Nam_key] = {Age_value,Grade_value}

print(stud_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken an empty dictionary as f and updated the values in f as name,password or balance are keys.

```
f=dict()
f.update(name=input(),password=input(),balance=input())
print(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Take input from user**:

```
input = int(input("enter a n value:"))

dict = {}


    name = input() 

    values = int(input()) 

    dict[name] = values
print(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
d = {}
count = 0
data = int(input("How many data do you want to enter?(numbers only): "))
while count < data:
    count = count + 1
    print("Enter a key")
    key = input()
    print("Enter a value")
    value = input()
    d[key] = value
    if count >= data:
        break

print(d)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).