# How to make a dictionary and set Key and Set Value from User Input? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I hope this isn't a duplicate, I searched and could not find any answers. So I am curious how to make user input set to a key or value. A good example is a registering Username and Password program, You set the Key to Username and the value the password the user that just registered entered to that Username key. Ex: "ExampleName : Example Pass". Other questions said dict{input} but that only makes a key. how can a make a key for one input then make a value for that Key In another input? Thanks. For those who said this was a duplicate, this is different. The other answers to the other don't specify how to set specific inputs to values.

```
#Example
username_pass = {}

username_register = input("Register your username and create it.")
#Set this to a Key
password_register = input("What password do you want for this username?"
#Set this to the value for that key
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a dictionary in Python from input values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147369/make-a-dictionary-in-python-from-input-values)

Comment: For entering a password without echoing, please look at [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html)

Comment: How did you not find this basic technique when you searched out tutorials on Python dictionary use?

Comment: I learned dictionaries a long time ago, easy to forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a dictionary

```
>>> dir_created = {}
>>> username = str(input('Enter username'))
>>> password = str(input('Enter password'))
>>> dir_created[username]=password
```

most important make a key as a string

Comment: Incorrect. Key need not be only string. It can be any hashable object.

Comment: Use anything . But in your case its more convenient identifier .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
userDict = {}
userDict[username_register] = password_register
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. After getting the username and password using `input()`, just do

```
username_pass[username_register] = password_register
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, to make this ridiculously easy:

```
>>> test = { input(): input() }
bob
password
>>> test
{'bob': 'password'}
```